# Adobe AIR NativeProcess Hello World

Tags: air

I have the following:

```
<body>
<script>
var myAIRFile = new air.File('C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows NT/Accessories/Wordpad.exe');
var myProcess = new air.NativeProcess();
var myStartup = new air.NativeProcessStartupInfo();
myStartup.executable = myAIRFile;
myProcess.addEventListener(air.ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, myOutputData);
myProcess.start(myAIRFile);

function myOutputData(myEvent){
    alert('success!');
}
</script>
</body>
```

And I've added

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

to Application.xml, so I know that NativeProcess is supported.
But I'm getting:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.filesystem::File@60dfdc1 to flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo.

I know that C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows NT/Accessories/Wordpad.exe exists because I can paste it into Explorer.
Maybe I have to escape the slashes or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this a little further, I see that you are passing the wrong argument type to the start() method of the NativeProcess

MyProcess.start() is expecting an argument of type: NativeProcessStartupInfo

Reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

So you need to be passing it the myStartUp variable. But i think you need to pass myAirFile into the "executable" property of myStartUp first.  So maybe something like:

myStartup.executable = myAirFile;

myProcess.start(myStartup);

I have not tested any of this. I am just going based on how I am reading the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Dean!  You and Ray both got it.

Answer (score 2):

You passed the file to myProcess. I believe you need to pass myStartup. Ie, myProcess.start(myStartup).